# Homebrew doctor crashes

Tags: crash, homebrew, brew-doctor

I just upgraded & updated my homebrew and now if I run `brew doctor`, I get the following errors and it fails to run. May I deleted the unexpected header files or is there a better solution?

`Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.6) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.7:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org`

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/eio-emul.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ev-emul.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/eio.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ev.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you just need to upgrade the XQuartz in your system and ignore all the other warnings.

You may build some software that utilise X11 components, so just go to https://xquartz.macosforge.org/, download and install the latest version.

It is obvious that you install node.js without using homebrew so that the header files are added into /use/local/include/ not via homebrew and confuse it. Unless you encounter some kind of problems as mentioned in the warning message, you can just ignore them.

Comment: Thanks. I moved `/usr/local/include/node` to some other location and updated XQuartz manually. I expected XQuartz and other brew-cask installed softwares to be updated by brew-cask itself.